# Exclude a value in Java

Tags: java, sum, average

I've become a bit stuck with my Java program.
The user can enter as many values as they want and then type "999" to get the sum and average of all the values they entered.

Everything about this works apart from when it comes to entering "999".
It does indeed display the sum and average when it's entered, but it also includes the "999" value in the sum and average calculation.

I'm curious if there's any way to exclude this specific value from the calculation and merely use it to exit the loop and display the sum and average outputs.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumAvg {
static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sum = 0, newNumber = 0, amount = 0;
    double average;

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

    do {
        amount++;
        newNumber = reader.nextInt();
        sum = sum + newNumber;
    } while (newNumber != 999);

    average = (sum / amount) * 1.0;
    System.out.printf("Sum: %s %nAverage: %.2f",sum,average);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (newNumber != 999) {...}`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, * 1.0 does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't increase amount until you have a valid number. Don't sum unless you have a valid number. Cast to `double` *before* division, otherwise it's an integer division.

```
int sum = 0, amount = 0, newNumber;
System.out.println("Enter numbers. Enter 999 to stop:");
while ((newNumber = reader.nextInt()) != 999) {
    sum += newNumber;
    amount++;
}
double average = (double)sum / amount;

NumberFormat numfmt = NumberFormat.getInstance();
numfmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
numfmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(9);
numfmt.setGroupingUsed(true);
System.out.println("Sum: " + numfmt.format(sum));
System.out.println("Average: " + numfmt.format(average));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you're reading the new number in before checking if it's the number you're excluding; the `do-while` loop will not stop while it's running if the condition is no longer satisfied at the end, but instead will wait until the code is done executing.

So, once you input the number `999`:

```
do {
    amount++;
    newNumber = reader.nextInt(); // reads in 999
    sum = sum + newNumber; // adds it to your sum
    // and after adding it to the sum, it will execute the while
    // condition again, and check if it should repeat the loop.
} while (newNumber != 999);
```

So, possible solutions include reordering the code:

```
newNumber = reader.nextInt();
while(newNumber != 999){
    amount++;
    sum += newNumber;
    newNumber = reader.nextInt();
}
```

So, after each new number is read in, it will jump to the top of the block and check the while condition again, so a check happens before each sum (which makes sense; the check comes right before the sum in this block of code, so it should follow that the sum can only happen after the condition is satisfied.)

You could also add an if-statement to the center of your code,

```
do {
    newNumber = reader.nextInt();
    if(newNumber == 999) break;  // if we get 999, break out of the loop completely
    amount++;
    sum = sum + newNumber;
} while (true);
```

Or, you could even consider using a different method of breaking out of the loop; for example, waiting for an `EOF` (`^D`) character helps you prevent the issue of someone actually wanting to add the number 999 to their total, by waiting for a character specifically designed to designate the end of someone's input. (So this also would allow you to read from files seamlessly with your program).

```
try {
    while(true){
        newNumber = reader.nextInt();
        amount++;
        sum += newNumber;
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex){}
// continue your code here
```

This will continue executing the inside code until a `NoSuchElementException` is raised by an `EOF` character, and when it is, it will break out of the inside loop. Therefore, no number is required to be excluded and used as a number to break out of the loop.

**EDIT**: As Andreas pointed out, this last solution will also intercept input that can not be read as an integer (like "1", "2", "3abc" will only sum `1` and `2`) by `reader.nextInt()` as invalid and will exit the loop as if the end of the input has been reached, so handling for that would be required depending on if you expect the output to be invalid.

Comment: 2nd code block doesn't increase `amount`. 3rd code block increases `amount` once too many. 4th block will never terminate because `nextInt` doesn't consume the newline.

Comment: oh, thanks - I fixed the `amount`s right after posting, I'm taking a look into `.hasNextLine`, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, all the code blocks should be working as intended now.

Comment: Makes it a bit lax, since it will stop on the first invalid input, e.g. `1 2 3g` will process `1` and `2`, then exit loop without processing `3g`, without error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check if the newNumber != 999, do your calculation like this:

```
   int sum = 0, newNumber = 0, amount = 0;
    double average;

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

    while(reader.hasNext()) {
        newNumber = reader.nextInt();
        if(newNumber != 999) {
            amount++;
            sum = sum + newNumber;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    average = (sum / amount) * 1.0;
    System.out.printf("Sum: %s %nAverage: %.2f",sum,average); 
    return;
```

Hope this help!